# How to solve HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for URL inRobot Frame work

Tags: api, postman, robotframework

I know there are many similar kinds of questions available but none of them worked.
Can someone tell me if there is any kind of syntax error for the Testcase below

```
Create Token
    Create Session      testsession        ${baseUrl}       verify=true
    ${body}=    create dictionary    clientId=unittest.cc.client        clientSecret=RyDQ$xxxxxRtv
    ${header}=  create dictionary    Content-Type=application/json
    ${resp}=    POST On Session    testsession    ${reqUri}    json=${body}    headers=${header}    params=${ApiKeyParameter}
    ${source data}=    Evaluate     json.loads("""${resp.content}""")    json
    ${token}=   Set Variable   ${source data['accessToken']}

   #No errors Uptill this much - Bearer token creation was successful after that getting error while using it

    ${header}=   create dictionary       Authorization=${tpre} ${token}     Content-Type=application/json      cookies=ss-id=KF84fFy4txxxxxxxxx76i; ss-pid=StDTDxxxxxxxxxxxxn7r
    ${body}=    get file    API/data.txt
    log to console    ${header}
    ${resp}=    post on session     testsession     /orders     json=${body}    headers=${header}
    log to console    ${resp.status_code}
```

The problem is every time I run the test I am getting a 400 error. Below is the Python code provided by POSTMAN and the screenshots of the headers used. Now I am not sure of how to get the **HOST** header in my python or maybe robot framework.
Please let me know if any additional details are needed. I am not sure of headers in the URL formation while get or post request is done
Is there any way to find that out?

```
import requests
import JSON

url = "https://domain:10001/orders?format=json"

payload = json.dumps({ Can ignore this part
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'ss-id=xxx; ss-pid=xxx'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

[image]

Comment: It's all in the actual data - both headers and payload - you're sending to the server, and that is the portion you've skipped in the question. Error 400 means the server "is not happy" with that data, there's an issue with it; the easiest way is to check the server's logs, if it writes the reason for rejection. What's the value of `${tpre}` - it should be the string Bearer, and you may want to use directly that, not a var. Are you sure the content of that txt file is a proper json string - if not, that would be another reason for the server to reject the request.

Comment: I'm guessing it's this: `clientId=unittest.cc.client`. You're setting clientid to the literal string "unitest.cc.client".

Comment: @TodorMinakov
It's a bearer Token so I have assigned a pre-value of  'bearer' to the variable ```${tpre}```

Comment: @BryanOakley
Yes, that can be one of the reasons thanks for pointing that out let me check once.
And Again,
as per TodorMinakov said the body can be one of the reasons let me check the response content there must an error message.

Will get back soon.

Comment: @TodorMinakov The error was in the format of the body because of some extra space.
Thanks for pointing that out.
Bryan Oakley Thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you all ever come across this kind of issue don't forget to check the body of the JSON / XML you are sending.
Mine resolved as I was saving the dump JSON in a text file so while reading from the file my code was adding some extra spaces in front so I was getting a 400 error.

For further information try logging the **Response Content** it must show you the error message.